# Allowing 'context' to travel to different dart files

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently have a Navigator.push(context, *route*) but the context portion is returning an error, After trying to debug I found that the issue was because i was calling a function vs setting the home directly to the widget tree. But now i'm not sure how I can get the context to communicate to the build? Not sure if this was well explained but hopefully looking at the code clarifies my issue.

passing 'context' in the mainview() function, get a runtime error.

```
class _MyAppmain extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
            //theme data
            primaryColor: Color(0xffA3E4D7),
            accentColor: Color(0xffECF0F1),
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat'), 
        home: mainView());//this is where the function in the other file is called
  }
}
```

second file:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context, NewEventTransition());//the issue
          },
          mini: true,
        ),
```

this is a very small chunk of the file but I think it should be enough.

Wanting to be able to get context across the two files through the function but I get an error instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Navigator` is a widget just like `Scaffold` but much more near the top of the widget tree.
calling `Navigator.of(context)` will get you the navigator widget in the context's widget tree.
[when the fab is pressed, there is definitely a Navigator in the widget tree. maybe each context can only find widgets with lower depth in the widget tree]

a fix would be to use a named route builder instead of a function call:

```dart
class _MyAppmain extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        //theme data
          primaryColor: Color(0xffA3E4D7),
          accentColor: Color(0xffECF0F1),
          fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/' : (context) => mainView(context),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: appreciate the response!